# NGINX reverse proxy rewrite SAML callback

Tags: nginx, sonarqube, reverse-proxy, saml-2.0

SonarQube on windows, running on http://localhost/9000.

I'm setting up NGINX to use as a reverse proxy and serve on https://localip.com.

I'm getting the following EE when trying to connect to SonarQube

> You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator. Reason: The response was received at http://localhost:9000/oauth2/callback/saml instead of https://localip.com/oauth2/callback/saml

I'm guessing I need to instruct NGINX to rewrite the callback, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You don't show a sample config, but I recently hit the same issue as you when setting up SonarQube 9 behind an nginx reverse proxy w/ SAML.

> You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator. Reason: The response was received at http://localhost:9000/oauth2/callback/saml instead of https://localip.com/oauth2/callback/saml

The most likely fix for this is to add these 2 lines to your server proxypass section in your nginx proxy config:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

Sonarsource had [a post  about this](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-users-lets-talk-about-iis-and-saml-authentication/33505) for IIS reverse proxies, where they indicate 2 important things:

1. That HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO is set to https
2. That host headers are preserved

The lines in my above code snippet handle the NGINX equivalents for #1 and #2 in that order.

Their [Operating the Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/operate-server/) page also gives this sample config:

```
# the server directive is Nginx's virtual host directive
server { 
 # port to listen on. Can also be set to an IP:PORT 
 listen 443 ssl;
 ssl_certificate ${path_to_your_certificate_file}
 ssl_certificate_key ${path_to_your_certificate_key_file}
 location / {
   proxy_pass ${address_of_your_sonarqube_instance_behind_proxy}
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
 }
}
```

Based on your error message, the proxy_pass line will most likely something like `proxy_pass http://localhost:9000`. That's how I set mine up as well.

Comment: I have the same setup with Google as IdP, but after a successful auth sonarqube gives me this log: ` login failure [cause|User must be authenticated][method|BASIC][provider|LOCAL|local`. So even though it sends the saml AuthNRequest, it thinks that the provider is local and gives me 401. I have these and the rest of the params set in the UI: 

sonar.auth.saml.enabled=true
sonar.auth.saml.applicationId=sonarqube
sonar.auth.saml.providerName=SAML

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue, but i run Apache server , and my proxy configuration is as follow:

```
  ## Proxy rules
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

what solve issue is adding :

```
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `https://{sonarqube_domain}/admin/settings` and make sure `Server base URL` is set to `https://{sonarqube_domain}`