# SonarQube Azure AD integration not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am hosting Sonarqube on windows VM with IIS and reverse proxy configured to support SSL certificate.
All works for basic (user/password) authentication but I got problem making Azure AD authentication work

I followed instructions to setup Azure AD integration. I have configured Azure AD integration, provided correct Client ID, new Secret, correct tenant ID, Base server url is correct no ending "/".

Despite all steps executed properly Azure AD authentication doesn't work: when I click  on button to logon using Microsoft login page sends requests and I am redirected back to logon page

I use Sonarqube 8.0.0.29455 with plugin Azure AD Authentication version 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check with below points:

1. The redirect URL should be configured with a correct URL,
   `e.g. https:// sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad`. Here /oauth2/callback/aad is a must in addition to the application URL. The redirect URL must have a `https` or loopback address, else the Azure AD login will not work.
   For example, if your main URL is "https://sonarqube.example.com", you would enter "https://sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad"
2. Set the required permissions in portal and grant consent if required

   i)  Sign in and read user profile

   ii) Read all users’ basic profiles
3. Check the rewrite rule when  [Running SonarQube behind an IIS Reversed Proxy | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudioalmrangers/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy)
4. Make sure you aren’t behind a firewall .

Try upgrading sonarqube
Restart everything after any changes made.

**References:**

1. [Setup · hkamel/sonar-auth-aad Wiki (github.com)](https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad/wiki/Setup)
2. [Azure AD integration with sonarqube - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990417/azure-ad-integration-with-sonarqube)

Comment: Points 1 and 2 were checked and are fine. I am going to check 3 and 4 today

Comment: Went through 3 and 4 and still got same problem. In fact I did miss Outbound Rule and "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" but even after changing this still got same problem.

Connection should not be blocked, i tried this url:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://<public_name>/oauth2/callback/aad&scope=openid&response_type=code

 to simulate authentication event and connectivity works but i am redirected to the page with error:
You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.