# SonarQube to Azure AD is failing with 401 error in logs

Tags: azure-active-directory, sonarqube

I have nginx-->SonarQube.
nginx is able to forward requests successfully.
We want to integrate Authentication with Azure AD.
We followed instructions from here:
https://www.emtec.digital/think-hub/blogs/sonarqube-integration-azure-active-directory/

So when I access https://mycompany.com, I get login page  which has "Login with Microsoft" and More options(you can login with local user).
When I enter username and password for Microsoft , we see that Azure AD is returning the token, but SonarQube rejects after that. I see that in the sonarqube access log

"GET /api/navigation/global HTTP/1.1" **401** - "https://mycompany.com/sonar/oauth2/callback/aad?co

So it goes back to login page again. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check with below points:

1. Try upgrading sonarqube to the latest version.
2. The redirect URL should be configured with a correct URL, e.g. https:// sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad. Here /oauth2/callback/aad is a must in addition to the application URL. For example, if your main URL is "https://sonarqube.example.com" in sonar server base url , you would enter "https://sonarqube.example.com/oauth2/callback/aad" as redirect url in aad.
3. Make sure the user has required role or permissions to access .
   Set the required [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) in portal and grant consent if required
   i)  Sign in and read user profile
   ii) Read all users’ basic profiles
4. Also please  check [http redirection  - Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69990417/azure-ad-integration-with-sonarqube) .The redirect URL must have a https or loopback address, else the Azure AD login will not work.
   Try clearing the cookies and Restart after any changes made

Referencs:

1. [sonar-auth-aad (github)](https://github.com/hkamel/sonar-auth-aad/wiki/Setup)
2. [running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudioalmrangers/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy)
3. [docs.sonarqube.org](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/delegated-auth/)

Comment: Fantastic!. Thanks a lot Kavya. Found the problem.  We did everything except 2 things. Reply URL I had an extra like /sonar in the middle. Not sure if this made a difference . I enabled logging and found that Client Secret was wrong. Anyone who wants to integrate SonarQube to Azure AD, this is great place to look!.

Comment: Done!. thanks again.